# Why are the words 戒 and 戎 written similarly?

Tags: characters, glyph-origin

Why are these words written similarly? Do they descend from a common Chinese character? If so, how do you explain the difference in pronunciations among derived words, especially for 戎?

投笔从**戎** róng
盗**贼** zéi
**绒**毛 róng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characters resemble each other because 「戒」 was subject to a slight amount of structural shuffling and the original lower-left component of 「戎」 is of a simple shape, so most people won't recognise what it actually is.

> As far as I can recall, the only other place that the lower-left component of 「戎」 occurs in is the top of 「古」.

「戒」 and 「戎」 aren't the same character, they don't descend from the same character, and the [morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) they represent aren't related (except in the sense of semantics - both are pictographs containing [「戈」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=127), [*dagger-axe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe)).

It follows that they sound completely different, whether as individual characters or as part of a phonetic hint function in other characters.

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)657
[合集7060](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=7060&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
戒叔尊
[集成5856](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5856&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
[為](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)33
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「戒」 depicts *two hands* [「廾」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=60) holding up a *dagger-axe* 「戈」, indicating the meaning *to warn/caution*. 「廾」 later migrated to the lower-left of the character and no longer appears to be holding up the weapon anymore; the structural analogy to the original form is 「」.

---

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
[拾](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)9.12
[合集6890](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6890&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image]
班簋
[集成4341](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4341&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

「戎」 depicts a *dagger-axe* 「戈」 together with a *shield*, indicating the meaning *armaments*.

> *Shield* is now written as 「盾」. The original character doesn't exist individually anymore, but remains as the top component of [「古」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=200) (*solid, sturdy*, now written as 「固」).
>
> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image]
> [林](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.24.6
> [合集16347](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=16347&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 秉毌父乙爵
> [集成8871](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=8871&jgwfl=)</kbd>
>
> This character was later replaced by the new character 「盾」, which depicts a side view of the shield with an *eye looking straight* [「直」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1034) peering from underneath the cover of the shield.
>
> <kbd>西周
> 金
> [image]
> 五年師簋
> [集成4216](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4216&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
> 簡
> [image]
> [效](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)3
> 睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>今
> 楷
> [image]</kbd>

---

As for 「賊」, it doesn't actually contain 「戎」. 「賊」 (Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*k.dzˤək/**, *to ruin/damage/destroy*) is comprised of semantic 「戈」 (*dagger-axe*) and phonetic [「則」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1140) (**/*[ts]ˤək/**). The 「刂」 part was later corrupted into a 「」 shape, causing the right hand side of 「賊」 to be misinterpreted as 「戎」.

<kbd>西周
金
[image]
散氏盤
[集成10176](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10176&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
簡
[image]
[法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)76
睡虎地秦簡</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
韓勑碑陰</kbd>
　<kbd>今
楷
[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

As for the auxiliary question, why 贼 is pronounced so differently to 戎 / 绒, that's because 贼's phonetic component is not on the right hand side, but kind of on the left hand side.

Although modern 賊 is written as ⿰貝戎, [in the Bronze Script](https://hanziyuan.net/#%E8%B3%8A) it was ⿹戈則, where 則 is the phonetic. The phonetic correspondences are thus not too bad:

- modern standard Mandarin: 則 *zé* vs 賊 *zéi*;
- Cantonese: 則 *zak1* vs 賊 *caak6*;
- Min Nan - Hokkien (literary): 則 *chek* vs 賊 *che̍k*;
- Min Dong - Fuzhounese: 則 *cáik* vs 賊 *chĕk*
- Wu - Shanghainese: 則 *tseq* vs 賊 *zeq*
- Middle Chinese: 則 = 子德切 /t͡sək̚/ vs 賊 = 昨則切 /d͡zək̚/

Comment: Thanks for catching that question, I missed it completely. I’ve amended my answer to show the paleography of 賊.